# ¿Como leer datos de un request?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando una aplicación en laravel y tengo un formulario que al ser enviado genera estos datos.
Lo pego como json que es la respuesta que me da cuando pongo en la función return $request

```
{"_method":"PUT","_token":"XRviFBM8l0x35shr7dKG0RsisRWIzk9q5xKynnZP","1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":"1h....16    2h....46","5":null,"6":null,"7":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":"67","11":"29","12":"0","13":"3","14":"1","15":"0","16":null,"17":null,"18":null,"19":null,"20":null,"21":null,"22":null,"43":"73.80","44":null,"45":null,"46":"33.02","47":"15.42","48":"0.76","49":null,"50":null,"51":null,"52":null,"53":null,"54":"4.01","55":null,"56":null,"57":null,"58":null,"59":null,"60":null,"61":null,"62":null,"63":null,"64":null,"65":null,"66":null,"67":null,"68":null,"69":null,"580":null,"581":"Dil ...... 1\/64"}
```

Necesito acceder al valor del índice y al valor del value, pero cuando uso por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($request as $idresultado => $valorresultado)
```

me devuelve en $idresultado, el índice que necesito, pero en $valorresultado me sale cualquier disparate, primero que nada me devuelve un array y todo lo que tiene dentro es cualquier cosa que no entiendo, alguien puede ayudarme?
Por si acaso, los null que aparecen es porque dejaron el input vacio.

Comment: intenta con `$requet->all()` no estoy seguro que funcione pero podrias intentar, podrias mostrar tambien el codigo del formulario, ya que recibir datos `null` no parece normal

Comment: Si funciono muchas gracias

Comment: Cierra la pregunta por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener un array asociativo con todos los valores de la request debes de utilizar `$request->all()`

```php
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $data = $request->all();
    foreach($data as $field => $value) {
        //
    }
}
```

Te dejo la documentación de [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: Si funciono correctamente gracias.

Comment: Por favor, cierra la pregunta cuando puedas :)